# Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека для создание голосового помощника на python?

Tags: python

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека для создания голосового помощника на python? Только я хочу, чтобы эта библиотека работала с наушниками, а не с микрофоном. Т.е. хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было командовать с наушника, а не по микро.

Comment: speech_recognition вроде так.............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О том, как обрабатывать речь на Python, рассказывается в [этой статье](https://learn4kid-python.firebaseapp.com/python_data_structure/python_speech_recognition/). В принципе документации и статей в интернете по работе с модулем SpeechRecognition очень много, в этом случае уже ваш простор фантазии — документация вам расскажет куда больше, чем я.

Касательно выбора микрофона, с которого модуль будет слушать вас — это настраивается при инициализации `speech_recognition.Microphone(device_index=N)`. Здесь N — индекс девайса, который можно получить, просмотрев полный список
подключенных микрофонов в `speech_recognition.Microphone.list_microphone_names()`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать vosk для распознания речи офлайн, pyaudio, speech_recognition, и т.д. Озвучить текст можно с помощью pyttsx3.